# Use cache-control header in a java client

Tags: java, http, caching, client, cache-control

From a Java application, using `CXF`, I call rest web services.
The rest `ws` respond using HTTP Headers 1.1 cache-control (max-age, no-cache ...).

From the java client, how can I use these headers?
Are there any framework / tool / example to use them and to cache data as it should?

All the articles I could find only talk about the creation of these server-side headers, but nothing on client side.

**UPDATE :**
In fact, the question is :
is there any tool to help implement in a java client the same behavior as in a browser to process cache-control header ?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to figure out. A CXF client has all the information it needs to automatically cache responses from the server that contain cache-control headers. I'm baffeled CXF apparently has no build-in support for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any framework / tool / example to use them and to cache data as it should?

If you're asking for a software library recommendation of a Java HTTP client library that respects `Cache-Control` in server responses, then:

- [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) supports caching in its [caching HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/caching.html)
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) supports caching

Both libraries are Apache-licensed and supported.

Answer (score 0):

Cache-control is just an HTTP header. How a client handles the header is client dependent, but these headers are created by a *server*; [see here](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) for an overview.

Comment: These headers are quite clear.
Their use is also clear and it seems relatively easy to provide a simple behavior to treat them.
Why not based on cachable annotation of spring ...